# Syncing Outlook personal distribution lists to

Tags: outlook, blackberry

I have a BlackBerry 8330 that is activated on our BES server. Is it possible to have personal distribution lists sync to the BlackBerry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean lists that you have created that are stored in Outlook's Contacts section, then the answer is no.  (At least for me, BB 8900 firmware 4.6, BES 4.1.5, Exchange 2003)